# How to preserve Linebrakes after reciving Text from Server (EditText)

Tags: android, android-edittext, line-breaks

I have an EditText:

```
<EditText
         android:id="@+id/NachrichtText"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_margin="5dp"
         android:background="@android:color/background_light"
         android:ems="10"
         android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                    />
```

Where the user can write messages. When the user hits the enter-key it works fine (the Cursor goes in the next line).

When the user is done he can click a button so that his message gets sent to the Server and saved in SharedPreferences.
When the user leaves the activity and returns, the message is received from SharedPreferences and the text is well formatted (line brakes are present).

But when the user Downloads the message from the Server, the message has no line breaks.

I tried to add `<br>` to the line breaks and ran the text through Spanned but it didn't really work.

Are there any other possibilities to keep line breaks that can be saved in the server? If possible also without HTML code.

Thank you

Comment: check if your server saves `\n` when saving data by manually sending a string which contains `\n` character

Answer (score 0):

Try using something like the following logic:

```
if the user presses the enter key{ 
    add a \n character to the string saved
}
```

I believe that this should work once the server receives the data as it will treat the "\n" character & create a new line. Just pressing OK might create a line break in the edit text but not in the string.

Hope it helps,